# how to set value to rating bar with string

Tags: android, ratingbar

I get a number from database as string.
I want to set this number (for example 3 or 4) to a rating bar.
But it says rating bar just accepts `float` variables.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse that STring to Float.You can do like this->

```
float rating = Float.parseFloat(string);
ratingBar.setRating(rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Float.parseFloat`, e.g.:

```
float val = Float.parseFloat("4");
```